# How to log PHP errors to both a log file and to stderr while leaving display_errors set to true?

Tags: php

I am trying to capture CLI errors written to `stderr` and email them.  I have this part working.

The problem is, I need `display_errors=true` and `error_log='file path'`.  When both these are used, php stops writing to `stderr`.  Is there a way to make it write to `stderr`, `stdout`, and the log?